# How to use the preserve keywords in the Pkg REPL?

Tags: julia

The behavior of Julia's `Pkg`, can be specified with the `preserve` keyword like this:

```
julia> Pkg.add("Plots", preserve=PRESERVE_DIRECT)
```

However I prefer to use `Pkg REPL`. Can I use the same keyword within the REPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You can prepend the packages with the `--preserve=<tier>` flag like this:

```
pkg> add --preserve=direct Plots
```

For all tiers of the resolve algorithm, see the [documentation](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1.5/repl/).